# I am getting error in radio box while i have used custom component in angular

Tags: angular

I have an issue in radio box. anyone have idea how do i fix that.  here is the code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-radio-v5

Comment: Please explain more!

Comment: Selection of radio box is not separating if you look at the preview. there is two different controls gender and declaration which is selected separately if someone select.

Comment: check this sample for more information: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-radio-button-and-checkbox-example

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs becouse of the for-in loop in the validate function.

It itterates over the error object and breaks on itteration 1.
The code tries to validate the input field fatherName which in this case does not exist and throws an error. You can check that by removing every property except the existing ones (gender and yesNo).

Adding and addition statement to the 'If' corrects the problem by checking if the desired input really exists before continuing.

```
if (input && input.valid && input.dirty)
```

Comment: Yes, @Qellson Thanks but the main issue is that if you select the gender that should be selected. and if you select declaration then that should be selected i mean the way radio box is work.  and that is i think changeEvent method we have to do some tweaks on it.